# Filebeat hint based autodiscovery - annotation format?

Tags: filebeat

I'm using filebeat with autodiscovery on kubernetes, I'm trying to add a hint as an annotation to my pod to exclude certain lines.

This annotation:

```
co.elastic.logs/exclude_lines
```

is [documented](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-autodiscover-hints.html#_co_elastic_logsexclude_lines) as a list of regular expressions, what is the format?

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    co.elastic.logs/exclude_lines: '["regex1","regex2"]'
    # or
    co.elastic.logs/exclude_lines: 'regex1|regex2'
    # or
    co.elastic.logs/exclude_lines: 'regex1,regex2'
```